# Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'object'

Tags: c#

I have following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<object, object>>> TestField { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to create a TestClass object like this:

```
new TestClass 
{
    TestField = new Expression<Func<OtherClass, object>>[]
    {
        otherClass => otherClass.FieldX,
        otherClass => otherClass.FieldY
    }
}
```

But I get following IntelliSense error:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'OtherClass' to 'object'**

How do I implement this with keeping my `TestClass` definition generic so I can create a `TestClass` object with e.g. `OtherClass`, `AnotherClass`, or any other class?

Comment: Why don't you make `TestClass` generic?

Comment: `new Expression<Func<object, object>>[] { otherClass => ((OtherClass)otherClass).FieldX, otherClass => ((OtherClass)otherClass).FieldY }`

Comment: "But I get following IntelliSense error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'OtherClass' to 'object'" -- Really? That doesn't sound right. Are you sure you're not getting a longer error message?

Comment: @hvd I think the actual message is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<OtherClass, object>>[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<object, object>>>'` - very different and much more useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
new TestClass
{
    TestField = new Expression<Func<object, object>>[]
    {
            otherClass => ((OtherClass)otherClass).FieldX,
            otherClass => ((OtherClass)otherClass).FieldY
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a generic class of one type to a generic class of a derived type. Just because the generic type of the classes are connected by inheritance doesn't mean the class itself is. For example, you cannot cast `List<Apple>` to `List<Fruit>`, because as far as the program is concerned, those two lists are completely different classes.

In your case, you can solve your generics issue by making `TestClass` itself generic:

```
public class TestClass<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> TestField { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of `TestClass` like so:

```
new TestClass<OtherClass>
{
    TestField = new Expression<Func<OtherClass, object>>[]
    {
        otherClass => otherClass.FieldX,
        otherClass => otherClass.FieldY
    }
}
```